# How to create a query that shows additional information from ISA relationships

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a database of Star Wars characters, and three tables:

```
Characters(cname, alias, gender, pname)

Droid(cname, dtype, mainskill)

JediSith(cname, level)
```

where `Droid` and `JediSith` have an IS-A relationship with `Characters` (non-covering, no overlap), and `cname` for both `Droid` and `JediSith` is a foreign key that references `Characters`.

How would I create a query that would show all the information from `Characters`, as well as the additional information from `JediSith` or `Droid` (where applicable), for a given `cname`?

Currently I have three queries, one for each table, that shows the relevant information from each table. Is it possible to make this into one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join the other two tables to `Characters`:

```
SELECT c.cname, c.alias, c.gender, c.pname, d.dtype, d.mainskill, j.level
FROM Characters c
LEFT JOIN Droid d ON d.cname = c.cname
LEFT JOIN JediSith j ON j.cname = c.cname
```

If you're running the query in MS Access, you need to use parentheses:

```
SELECT c.cname, c.alias, c.gender, c.pname, d.dtype, d.mainskill, j.level
FROM (Characters c
      LEFT JOIN Droid d ON d.cname = c.cname)
      LEFT JOIN JediSith j ON j.cname = c.cname
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it today, but I'll accept this answer because I should be able to get it to work if this doesn't (I think it will though) :)